# Copy data from firestore db to realtime db

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been working on small projects to learn more about firebase.

Currently I have some data in firestore db for each user. my goal is whenever any of the data fields is written or changed in firesotre all corresponding data fields for that user are copied over to realtime db.

Based on the guides and what I found online the code below is what i came up with

```
 exports.copyMemberToRealdb = functions.firestore
.document("Users/{userId}/membership/{mId}")
.onWrite((change, context) => { 
  admin.database().ref("Users")
  .child(context.params.userId)
  .child("membership")
  .child(context.params.mId).update(change.data());
 
 return "ok";
});
```

What I am seeing is that data is only written once to the realtime db when the membership is first created, and only copies one field to the realtime db.

How can i make it so all data fields are copied over to realtime db when the membership fields in the firestore are updated?

Comment: `change.data()` contains the entire data of the document that was written. So if you have more than one field in Firestore, it'll also be updated in RTDB with this code. You might want to `console.log(change.data())` and check its output in the Cloud Functions log. Aside from that, I'd probably use `.set` instead of `.update` as you seem to want RTDB to be a copy of Firestore, and not a possible superset.

Comment: started fresh with the project , redeployed my functions and am getting the following error
"change.data is not a function at exports.copyMemberToRealdb.functions.firestore.document.onWrite"

Comment: Can you show the **entire** code of your Cloud Function, including the imports?

Answer (score 0):

changed

.child(context.params.mId).update(change.data());

to

.child(context.params.mId).update(change.after.data());

and worked for me